# can grub detect an OS on another disk?

Tags: windows-10, grub, manjaro

I have 3 disks in my PC: 2 disks for Windows and 1 for manjaro. But when I turn on the PC it does'nt show me the option for booting from the Windows disks.

For manjaro I have this configuration of disks:
[disk1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6llqe.png)
[disk2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Tdo.png)

I have tried reinstalling grub and got nothing.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you installed Manjaro in UEFI mode? Dual-boot doesn't work if the systems are installed in different modes. And disabling Fast Startup in Windows is a must for dual-boot.